# How to limited show list in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want use this **library** : https://github.com/fiskurgit/ChipCloud

I can added my lists from server into this **chip clouds** and for this I write below code :

```
List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;

            mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
            for (String str : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
                cloudChipList.clear();
                cloudChipList.add(str);
                if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) {
                    fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(str);
                }
            }
```

In my code show all of list's data, but I want just show 5 data no all of data!
How can I change my above code for show just 5 item ?

Comment: you can add only 5 element in  cloudChipList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do like this using counter,if count is above 5 it does not add to the list cloudChipList.

```
 List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings;
    int count=0;
                mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
                for (String str : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
                    cloudChipList.clear();
               if(count<5){
                    cloudChipList.add(str);}
                    if (cloudChipList.size() > 0) {
                        fullSearchMini_didYouMeanLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChip(str);
                    }
count++;
                }
```

Comment: currently i m not able to communicate with you.do you have a problem we can solve it here

Answer (score 0):

You can limit data as much as you would like to limit from server side. You should use `Criteria` for that. If you use session, then this sample code would help:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(YourClassName.class);
criteria.setMaxResults(5);
if (criteria.list().size() > 0) {
   yourListName = (List<YourClassName>) criteria.list();
}
```

This code will limit the number of items sent from the server to `5` even if the list has `n` number of items.